# rescale with ffmpeg but keep the pixel density constant

Tags: ffmpeg, rescale

I have a 1280x720 video resolution
After I resized the video output was blurred more than the original video
How to output video is clearer

Answer (score 0):

There is no pixel density for a media displayed on a electronic display.

The physical space occupied by a video depends on

- physical size of the display
- display's current resolution
- window size of the video player

A video when rescaled to a higher resolution will lose sharpness.

Comment: Thank you all the time for helping me